# How to make new draggable Container whenever I click a button? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, containers

I'm new to Flutter.

I want to make something like powerpoint app.

If I click button, return draggable container.

So users can drag container to any place.

And If I click button again, return new draggable container again.

But it's too hard for me.

can anybody help me?

Comment: You need to use a combination of `Draggable`,  `Stack` and `Positioned` to achieve. Give it a try. Re post here once you have a bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this article can help you

> [A Deep Dive Into Draggable and DragTarget in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-draggable-and-dragtarget-in-flutter-487919f6f1e4)